# Android new shriking tool R8 does not reflect any change in APK size

Tags: android, dex, android-r8

When I add R8 to shrink the android dex size it is not working.
I've added this following line:

### gradle.properties:

```
android.enableR8=true
```

When tried to analyse my code I could not find any difference in my apk size.
Is it something else I am missing?

Should I add any proguard rules and enable progaurd by adding these lines:

## build.gradle

```
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: Do you analyze debug build?

Comment: Yes @MarcinOrlowski.

Comment: As R8 is a drop-in replacement for ProGuard you still need to configure shrinking as described on the page https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code. If you are using Android Studio 3.4 or later R8 is the default shrinker, and you don't need `android.enableR8=true`.

Answer (score 3):

As sgjesse suggested in his comment, you need to enable minification on all build types on which you want R8 to run.

E.g., if you want R8 to run on all release builds, use `minifyEnabled` like this in your app-level build.gradle:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
    }
  }
}
```

If you want R8 to also run on your debug builds, then you will need to use `minifyEnabled` for debug as well.

You posted this line as part of your question:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Using `proguardFiles` in this manner is only necessary if you have your own rules that you would like to apply in addition to those in the default `proguard-android.txt` file.

(You still need to use `android.enableR8=true` in your gradle.properties file to enable R8 instead of ProGuard if you are using a version of the Android Gradle Plugin/Android Studio before 3.4)